# ListView with custom item layout and CheckBox - item is not clickable

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, touch

I have a ListView with custom Layout for Item:

(ImageView, TextView, 2xImageView andd CheckBox).

I want my item to be clikable (st that OnItemClickListener get called), selectable (so I can select an item) and also that the CheckBox can be toggled and it changes its state.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to create your own listener for the rating bar like this..in your getView() method of your adapter.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
  View row=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
  ViewHolder holder=(ViewHolder)row.getTag();

  if (holder==null) {   
    holder=new ViewHolder(row);
    row.setTag(holder);

    RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener l=
                new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
      public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar,
                                    float rating,
                                    boolean fromTouch)  {
        Integer myPosition=(Integer)ratingBar.getTag();
        RowModel model=getModel(myPosition);

        model.rating=rating;

        LinearLayout parent=(LinearLayout)ratingBar.getParent();


      }
    };

    holder.rate.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(l);
  }

  RowModel model=getModel(position);

  holder.rate.setTag(new Integer(position));
  holder.rate.setRating(model.rating);

  return(row);
}
```

}

You can see a full example of something like this [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/FancyLists/RateList)